# Using the user's selected date format in a Razor page

Tags: javascript, c#, date, format, razor-pages

I have a Razor page that takes dates as input and displays the dates that have been entered in a table.

To input the date, I use `<input type="date" />` which [MDN states](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/date):

> The displayed date format will differ from the actual value — the displayed date is formatted based on the locale of the user's browser, but the parsed value is always formatted yyyy-MM-dd.

This works as described, showing the date in the User's choice date format. I can even change my Windows settings, reload the page, and see what I set it to.

The trouble comes from trying to convert the yyyy-MM-dd dates I have stored to the user selected format.

I have tried managing the display format at the server with C# `date.ToShortDateString()` which looked right on localhost, but displayed the CultureInfo from the server when I deployed to Dev.

I have also tried managing the display format as a last step with JavaScript `date.toLocaleDateString()` which seems to just pick the standard MM/dd/yyyy for en-US.

This is 2023, the browser *knows* what the user has selected, it is using with the `<input>`. How can I format my dates the same? (Preferably without extra libraries that are no longer supported.)

Comment: There are plenty questions on this topic... and it is still not possible. Without clarification on what you are willing to compromise on it is not possible to suggest for workarounds of lack of that information on server side (as browser don't send it up).

Comment: There's built in middleware for controlling request culture. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization?view=aspnetcore-7.0 based on query string, cookie or accept language header.

Comment: It's not always a good idea to format dates according to the browser default language. If the page is displayed in a particular language, dates, numbers, etc. should be formatted to be consistent with the language of the page. Also, the browser language may just be the default, not what the user's primary langauge.

Comment: You can use localization to change the display based on the user's selected culture: https://www.mikesdotnetting.com/article/345/localisation-in-asp-net-core-razor-pages-cultures